# Prove decreasing sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ : if $n > m \ge N$ then $a_n < a_m + \epsilon$.

b) Does every bounded sequence of this type converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is true. There is a subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$ converging to some point $a$. Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $N$ as in the definition. Then $a_n <a_{n_{k}}+\epsilon$ for all $n >N$ for al $k$ such that $n_k >N$. For $k$ sufficiently large we have $a_{n_{k}} <a+\epsilon$. Hence $a_n <a+2\epsilon$ for $n >N$. On the other hand, $a_{n_{k}} >a-\epsilon$ for $k$ sufficiently large and $a_{n_{k}} <a_m+\epsilon$ whenever $m >N$ and $k$ is so large that $n_k >N$. This gives $a_m >a-2\epsilon$ for $m >N$. Combining these two we get $|a_n-a| <2\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.